# Check if record exists inside create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My scenario:

I have `SaleItem` model, which stores `(:sale_id, :product_id, :quantity, :total_price)`.

```
class SaleItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sale
  belongs_to :product

  before_save :set_unit_price
  before_save :set_total_price
  before_save :set_total_disscounted_price

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price_pence
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

  private

    def set_unit_price
      self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    end

    def set_total_price
      self[:total_price] = quantity * set_unit_price
    end

    def set_total_disscounted_price
      self[:total_disscounted_price] =self[:total_price] - (self[:total_price] * self.sale.event.event_disscount) / 100
    end
end
```

My problem is, whenever I create new `SaleItem` object I want to check if the same record already exists and if it does then I just need to add up the `:quantity` and recalculate total price (in the model) according to the new `:quantity`.

What I am confused about is is it possible to check it within the create method?
So far I found this rails method  `first_or_create`.

This is my initial code from `SaleItem` controller

```
class SaleItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @sale = @sale_item.sale
    @sale_item = SaleItem.create(sale_item_params)
    @event = @sale.event

    if @sale_item.save
      redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
    else
      redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)

    end
  end

  private

  def sale_item_params
    params.require(:sale_item).permit(:sale_id, :product_id, :quantity)
  end
end
```

and then after I found `first_or_create` I started changing it to this, but havent finished as I am a bit stuck:

```
class SaleItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    @sale_item = SaleItem.where(sale_id: params[:sale_id], product_id: sale_item_params[:product_id]).first_or_create do |sale_item|
      sale_item.quantity = sale_item.quantity.to_i + sale_item_params[:quantity].to_i
    end

    @sale = @sale_item.sale
    @sale_item = SaleItem.create(sale_item_params)
    @event = @sale.event

    if @sale_item.save
      redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
    else
      redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)

    end
  end

  private

  def sale_item_params
    params.require(:sale_item).permit(:sale_id, :product_id, :quantity)
  end
end
```

**I couldn't figure out how to update record that was found and dont change newly created record, so I created a variable `@new_record` and set it initially to `false`, and then once new record created, `@new_record` changes to `true`. In this way I was being able to track each record and change it if needed.**

**This is the `SaleItem Controller` updated code**

```
class SaleItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    @new_record = false

    @sale_item = SaleItem.where(sale_id: params[:sale_id], product_id: sale_item_params[:product_id]).first_or_create do |sale_item|
      sale_item.quantity = sale_item_params[:quantity]
      @new_record = true
    end

    @new_record == false ? @sale_item.quantity = @sale_item.quantity.to_i + sale_item_params[:quantity].to_i : sale_item_params[:quantity].to_i

    @sale = @sale_item.sale
    @event = @sale.event

    if @sale_item.save
      redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
    else
      redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @sale_item = SaleItem.find(params[:id])
    @sale = @sale_item.sale
    @event = @sale.event
    @sale_item.destroy
    redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)

  end

  private

  def sale_item_params
    params.require(:sale_item).permit(:sale_id, :product_id, :quantity)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `create` action code from this

```
def create

  @sale_item = SaleItem.where(sale_id: params[:sale_id], product_id: sale_item_params[:product_id]).first_or_create do |sale_item|
    sale_item.quantity = sale_item.quantity.to_i + sale_item_params[:quantity].to_i
  end

  @sale = @sale_item.sale
  @sale_item = SaleItem.create(sale_item_params)
  @event = @sale.event

  if @sale_item.save
    redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
  else
    redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
  end
end
```

to this

```
def create

  @sale_item = SaleItem.find_or_create_by(sale_item_params) do |sale_item|
    sale_item.quantity = sale_item.quantity.to_i + sale_item_params[:quantity].to_i
    sale_item.save
  end

  @sale = @sale_item.sale
  @event = @sale.event

  if @sale_item.save
    redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
  else
    redirect_to event_sale_path(@event, @sale)
  end
end
```

`find_or_create_by(sale_item_params)` will first find the sale_item with `sale_id`, `product_id` and `quantity` and then if there isn't any sale_item record found it will create a new one, In both case you can update the quantity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I still have a bit of uncertainty, because if I use `find_or_create_by(sale_item_params)` then if the sale_id and product_id match but quantity doesnt (in case if user enters quantity: 4, but the existing record in the db has same sale_id and product_id but different quantity value then it wont match these two records.) Thats why I am trying to find just by the sale_id and product_id, but I am failing, like I can find the record but cant add up quantities and save the record

Comment: Hey. @DavidSarvasidze sorry thats my bad, replace `sale_item_params`  with `sale_id: sale_item_params[:sale_id], product_id: sale_item_params[:product_id]` in `find_or_create_by`

Comment: Thank you, I figured that out but could you help me with one more thing please. I need to add `:quantities` only when an existing record is found. As I understand I should do it outside the `find_or_create_by` block, because inside the block we create a new record if no record found. At the moment I have this straight after the block `@sale_item.quantity = @sale_item.quantity.to_i + sale_item_params[:quantity].to_i ` but I am sure this is rubbish because if the record is new then it will add up its `:quantity` twice!? Maybe you have a suggestion, would much appreciate it. let me kno if unclear

Comment: Figured it out and updated my post, Thank you for help =)))

Answer (score 0):

My guess it you probably want to look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Comment: While APIDock had a good run, it's defunct now and out of date. Try linking to the [current documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) instead.

Comment: Too bad, I liked apidock. Updated the link.

Comment: It's really a shame it's stopped being updated because it's a fantastic tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define the unique key to find `SaleItem`

- for example, if `sale_id` and `product_id` are keys to find `SaleItem`.
- it's better to have new strong parameter method for find or create `SaleItem` on `create` method.

controller example:

```
    class SaleItemsController < ApplicationController
        before_action :initialize_sale_item, only: [:create]

        def create
            @sale_item.assign_attributes(sale_item_params)
            @sale_item.save
            # render or respond_to ...
        end

        private
        def sale_item_params
            params.require(:sale_item).permit(:sale_id, :product_id, :quantity)
        end

        def sale_item_key_params
            params.require(:sale_item).permit(:sale_id, :product_id)
        end

        def initialize_sale_item
            @sale_item = SaleItem.find_or_initialize_by(sale_item_key_params)
        end
    end
```

- as `Talha Junaid` suggested, you can use `find_or_create_by` instead of using `find_or_initialize_by`(and remove `initialize_sale_item` ...)
- references

  - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by
  - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by